# IF statement using TIME

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to write an IF statement to look at a range for time and return either Shift A or Shift B.

This is my formula that isn't working:

```
=IF(F2>TIME(6,0,0),IF(F2<TIME(16,0,0)),"A","B")
```

Comment: Thank you that is excatly what I was looking for. For some reason my sentax was not right when I tried the AND.

Answer (score 3):

Use [=AND](http://spreadsheets.about.com/b/2010/08/06/excel-and-function-2.htm) where both (or more) conditions have to be met to result in TRUE. Then the second IF is not required. With:

```
=IF(AND(F2>TIME(6,0,0),F2<TIME(16,0,0)),"A","B")
```

Shift A applies to just after 06:00 hrs through to just before 16:00 hrs and Shift B otherwise. `IF` and `F` so intermingled in the same formula was a little unfortunate!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried with an =AND but had the syntax wrong and tried nesting an IF statement in an IF which did not work out.